# Get value from dictionary as reference

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, reference-type

I'm currently quite stuck with C# dictionaries. I'm trying to write a cache for a using a Dictionary, but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
class Program
{
    static Dictionary<int, Value> dict;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<int,Value>();
        Value v = new Value() { Hello = 1, Bye = "QWERTY"};
        dict.Add(1, v);
        Value c = dict[1];
        Console.WriteLine(c.Bye);
        dict[1] = new Value() { Hello = 2, Bye = "ASDF" };
        Console.WriteLine(c.Bye);
    }
}

class Value
{
    public int Hello {get;set;}
    public string Bye {get;set;}
}
```

Current Output:

```
QWERTY
QWERTY
```

Output I'm looking for:

```
QWERTY
ASDF
```

**EDIT:**

I managed to get it working now, using:

```
//dict[1] = new Value() { Hello = 2, Bye = "ASDF" };
dict[1].Hello = 2;
dict[1].Bye = "ASDF";
```

However, is there a way for me to update the whole value rather than manually updating each property?

Comment: You've given `dict[1]` a new reference. the `Value c` still has a reference to the old `dict[1]`.

Comment: Well, you're manually updating each property in the original code as well, so what's the difference?

Comment: What you did is much like `Value v = XXX; Value c = v; /* copies reference, now two references to same instance */ v = YYY; /* assigns new reference to another instance to v; v and c no longer refer the same instance */`. So this happens with variables too and is not really related to `Dictionary<,>`. Two variables can't be "linked" the way you want, so that assignments to one of them "auto-assigns" to the other one. The only situation with this behavior is method parameters with `ref` (or `out`) modifier.

Answer (score 0):

It is working correctly, the problem is you are using a reference (`c`) to your original instance. Your reference wont be updated automatically.

This demonstrates it doing what you want:

```
dict = new Dictionary<int,Value>();
Value v = new Value() { Hello = 1, Bye = "QWERTY"};
dict.Add(1, v);
Value c = dict[1];
Console.WriteLine(c.Bye);
dict[1] = new Value() { Hello = 2, Bye = "ASDF" };
Console.WriteLine(dict[1].Bye);//THIS LINE IS CHANGED
```

So just to clarify, you already are updating the whole value as per your requirements.

Just a recommendation, but it might help for you to explain what end result you are trying to achieve. There may be a much better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = dict[1] = new Value() { Hello = 2, Bye = "ASDF" };
```

Otherwise, what you want doesn't make sense to me. You have tell the language to assign c to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You do get value from dictionary as reference, but you should know what store in dictionary is also an reference, which you just assign another reference to it.